# How to Resize/Change position of custom created user control in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

Currently I need a solution in my coding.
I already create custom user control with add, edit, delete function using 3 buttons.

The problem is, when I add my user control to windows form, I cannot change the position, or resizing the button. I only can do moving for all buttons in my control.

Please help me related to this .

Thank you indeed.

Comment: Each control has a `[Control].Size`, `[Control].Left`, and `[Control].Top` properties to allow you to change the size, and position of the control

Comment: Thank you JayV for your reply. 
The problem is when mycontrol class added into winform, it looks like joined and cannot be move separately. I only can move for all button.

Comment: What does `MyControl` look like and what does the rest of the form look like? I think you should add a screenshot of the form, highlighting `MyControl`

Comment: Hi, Do you mean when adding your control at Design time, in the Visual Studio interface when you drag it off the toolbox, or do you mean you have some code to add it at runtime?